# Is there a simpler way to loop for error checking and quitting? (C-strings/Character Arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c-strings, code-cleanup

I've been writing an assignment where we're tasked with making a shopping cart program that tracks the customer's cumulative price.

**I'm not allowed to use strings, global variables, or user defined functions**
I'm strictly instructed to use only Character arrays and loops.

While my shopping cart program works fine, I was wondering if there is any way to simplify my code? I feel like I would be penalized for making the code overly complicated. I feel like my quit feature in particular is overly complicated. Is there a better, simpler way of implementing it without using strings or functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
char continueOrQuit;
char productName[900];
float productPrice;
float totalCost = 0;
int productQuantity = 0;
bool validResponse;

cout << "Welcome to SmartCart" << endl;
cout << "Simply enter the name of your product when prompted" << endl;
cout << "After you enter your product, enter the price when prompted \n\n";

//while ((productName[900] != 'D', 'o', 'n', 'e') || (productName[900] != 'd', 'o', 'n', 'e'))
//While im not done shopping
do
{

    cout << "Name of Product: "; // Prompt for product
    cin.getline(productName, 900); // Get the name
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Cost of Product: "; // Prompt for product cost
    cin >> productPrice; // Get the cost
    while ((!cin) || (productPrice < 0))
    {
        cout << "Invalid Input!! Try again!!" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Cost of Product: "; // Prompt again for product cost
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> productPrice;
    }
    cin.ignore(250, '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the garbage
    cout << endl;
     // if everything is correct, we set up the display and give the results.

        cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << "The item(s) \"" << productName << "\" has/have been added to your cart for $" 
        << productPrice << endl;
        totalCost = totalCost + productPrice; // Calculating the cumulative sum total
        cout << "Your shopping total so far is: $" << totalCost << endl; // Display the sum total
        productQuantity++; // Count the number of items in cart
        cout << "You have " << productQuantity << " item(s) in your cart." << endl; 
        // Display the amount of characters in the cart
        cout << "To quit shopping, type \"Q\". Otherwise, type \"C\" (Without quotation marks)"
        << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to continue shopping? (C/Q) : ";
        cin >> continueOrQuit;
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        continueOrQuit = tolower(continueOrQuit);
        if (continueOrQuit == 'q')
        {
            cout << "You have chosen to finish and check out." << endl;
            validResponse = true;
        }
        else if (continueOrQuit == 'c')
            validResponse = true;
        else
            cout << "You have to type either C or Q!" << endl;
            validResponse = false;
            while (!validResponse)
            {
                cout << "Would you like to continue shopping? (C/Q) : ";
                cin >> continueOrQuit;
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                continueOrQuit = tolower(continueOrQuit);

                if (continueOrQuit == 'q')
                {
                    cout << "You have chosen to finish and check out." << endl;
                    validResponse = true;
                }
                else if (continueOrQuit == 'c')
                    validResponse = true;
            }
} while (continueOrQuit == 'c');

cout << "Your checkout total is $" << totalCost << endl;
cout << "You are purchasing a total of " << productQuantity << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}`

Comment: If you'll notice, I attempted to just use a while loop. However it seems like the while loop didn't care whether I typed done or not. It would continue anyways.

Comment: Your existing `while` loop will go into an infinite loop if `cin` is closed (e.g. your program is run with the input piped from a file, and it reaches the end of file)

Comment: Sorry, I just ran the code again and it's having a problem when you  decide to quit (q). It runs two times before it actually accepts that the user wants to quit

Comment: TLama: Okay, sorry about that. Has it already been moved, or should I delete and repost there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a shorter version of your code.
mainly I removed extra code when you check input by putting a `do while` so the case of wrong input the re-input go back to the first try.

You also have a missing bracket in the last else, it cause you to re-enter q or c in case you already enter it correctly.

Here is the code, you can compare to the original.

```
int main()
{
    char continueOrQuit;
    char productName[900];
    float productPrice;
    float totalCost = 0;
    int productQuantity = 0;
    bool validResponse;

    cout << "Welcome to SmartCart" << endl;
    cout << "Simply enter the name of your product when prompted" << endl;
    cout << "After you enter your product, enter the price when prompted \n\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "Name of Product: "; // Prompt for product
        cin.getline(productName, 900); // Get the name
        cout << endl;
        do{
            cout << "Cost of Product: "; // Prompt for product cost
            cin >> productPrice; // Get the cost
            if(!cin || productPrice < 0){
                cout << "Invalid Input!! Try again!!" << endl << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            }
        }while ((!cin) || (productPrice < 0));

        cin.ignore(250, '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the garbage
        cout << endl;
         // if everything is correct, we set up the display and give the results.

        cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << "The item(s) \"" << productName << "\" has/have been added to your cart for $" 
        << productPrice << endl;
        totalCost = totalCost + productPrice; // Calculating the cumulative sum total
        cout << "Your shopping total so far is: $" << totalCost << endl; // Display the sum total
        productQuantity++; // Count the number of items in cart
        cout << "You have " << productQuantity << " item(s) in your cart." << endl; 
        // Display the amount of characters in the cart

        do{
            cout << "To quit shopping, type \"Q\". Otherwise, type \"C\" (Without quotation marks)"
            << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to continue shopping? (C/Q) : ";
            cin >> continueOrQuit;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            continueOrQuit = tolower(continueOrQuit);
            if(continueOrQuit == 'q' || continueOrQuit == 'c')
                validResponse = true;
            else
            {
                cout << "You have to type either C or Q!" << endl;
                validResponse = false;
            }
        }while(!validResponse);
        if (continueOrQuit == 'q')
        {
            cout << "You have chosen to finish and check out." << endl;
        }       
    } while (continueOrQuit == 'c');

    cout << "Your checkout total is $" << totalCost << endl;
    cout << "You are purchasing a total of " << productQuantity << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was hesitant about using OR because sometimes it creates "ambiguous" errors. But this definitely fixed the code. Unfortunately I can't get 'c' to indicate that the user wants to continue

Comment: Why is that? what happen when you type c?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. I didn't fully read your edit. I didn't include the do function. When I did that, I had to make a few adjustments but it works nicely. Thanks so much for your solution